# How to script an OLE component using Python

Tags: python, windows, scripting, activex, ole

I would like to use Python to script an application that advertises itself as providing an OLE component. How should I get started?

I don't yet know what methods I need to call on the COMponents I will be accessing. Should I use win32com to load those components, and then start pressing 'tab' in IPython?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"[Python and COM](http://www.boddie.org.uk/python/COM.html)" contains an example. OLE is related to COM and ActiveX so you should look for those terms.

"[Python Programming on Win32](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565926219/)" is a useful book. There is also a "[Python Win32](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/)" mailing list.

Answer (score 2):

You need the [win32com](http://python.net/crew/mhammond/win32/Downloads.html) package. Some examples:

```
from win32com.client.dynamic import Dispatch

# Excel
excel = Dispatch('Excel.Application')

# Vim
vim = Dispatch('Vim.Application')
```

And then call whatever you like on them.

Answer (score 2):

win32com is a good package to use if you want to use the IDispatch interface to control your objects, but it's slow.

comtypes is a better, native Python, package that uses the raw COM approach to talk to your controls.

WxPython uses comtypes to give you an ActiveX container window from Python.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the [python-win32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) package, and, in particular, at its win32com API.

Answer (score 0):

PythonWin (http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/), bundled with python-win32, comes with its own COM browser as part of its shell and debugging environment.