# Open PDF to Bookmark/Named Destination?

Tags: python, pdf, cmd, adobe-reader

I'm trying to open a PDF to a specific bookmark using python.

So far, I'm able to run the following command in Command Prompt and get exactly what I want (*last* is the name of a named destination inside the PDF test.pdf)

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /A "nameddest=last" "C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.pdf"
```

---

But when I go to Python and try using the subprocess module like this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /A "nameddest=last" "C:\\Users\\User\Desktop\test.pdf"'], shell=True)
```

I get "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect." Something I tried before this caused Adobe Reader to open, but give me a dialog box that had the same message

**Why does what happens changes when I run it in python? And how can I fix it?**

---

I'm running Anaconda 2.1.0 on Windows 8 and using Acrobat 10 to create Destinations. I've played around with python for 2-3 years, but don't know much more than someone with 1 semester of an intro programming class.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869584/how-to-change-page-of-already-open-pdf-in-python, it shows you how to open a pdf file on a specific page

Answer (score 3):

### FIXED:

I'm an idiot.

```
"C:\\Users\\User\Desktop\test.pdf"
```

is an invalid path because the \t  in \test.pdf is interpretted as a tab...
It works after adding changing it to \test.pdf.

Code for anyone with the same problem later:

```
import os
import subprocess

page = "3"  
path_to_pdf = os.path.abspath("C:\\Users\\User\Desktop\\test.pdf")
path_to_acrobat = os.path.abspath('C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe')


process = subprocess.Popen([path_to_acrobat, '/n', '/A', 'page=' + page, path_to_pdf], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

process.wait()
```

Comment: You also can use `r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.pdf"`. Flag `r` at the head of string is raw string in python.